# SSH without the login ID or password

Tags: ssh, login, password

My workstation is running `Linux Centos7` is part of a local network. Every computer in this local network is running `Linux Centos7` as well (the same build). 
Every time I `ssh` into a server, I need to enter my password and the login information. I would like to `ssh` without the need to do that every time. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look up ssh public key authentication or ssh-copy-id on this site or via Google. It will give you plenty of walkthroughs on how to do this. If you need any help, add where you are having trouble to your question.

Comment: I did google it but I really don't know how to do it. Could you please help me. i highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Follow the instructions. Any of the results on Google or on this site where it has been covered many times will help. If you get stuck, add where you are having trouble to your answer. If you're not going to do any research or attempt to accomplish anything on your own or show what you don't understand then it's difficult to help you as you aren't learning anything or getting any better.

Answer (score 2):

On your local machine, go to `terminal` and type the following:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh

$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
Choose no passphrase when asked and accept the default filename of id_rsa

$ scp id_rsa.pub <user>@<yourhost>:.ssh/authorized_keys
Provide your password when asked and that’s the last time you’ll have to do it!
```

#### References

- [Logging in without a password – certificates & ssh](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404025901/http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2009/02/04/logging-in-without-a-password-certificates-ssh/)

Comment: Correct.  You can also do this with any *nix on any network you can reach from your computer.  If you have weird hostnames or ips or ports to deal with, or like specific options, look into setting up your `~/.ssh/config` file appropriately.